# SQL get all qualified users

Tags: sql, oracle

For some reason I am really struggling with getting this query right. Maybe there is a concept I dont get. I have a table that has records for courses taken. So you can think of it like course_id, username, date_completed. And I have another table that holds all the requirements for in this case clients. That table looks like client_id, course_id. Lets call it Client_requirements.

So the client_requirements table can look like this:

```
client_id | course_id
1            3
1            4
1            7
```

The other table looks like this:

```
course_id| username| training_date
3          1234      date
4          1234      date
7          1234      date
7          4354      date
```

What I need to do is figure out based on the courses a user has taken is the user qualified. Qualified in this case just means they have taken all the courses the client requires. I feel like it's something obvious but my brain is melted at this point.

Im using oracle btw but I dont think that should matter for this kind of issue.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `join` with a `group by` . . . and then `having` to be sure all the courses are accounted for:

```
select uc.user_id, cr.client_id
from user_courses uc join
     client_requirements cr
     on uc.course_id = cr.course_id
group by uc.user_id, cr.client_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from client_requirements cr2 where cr2.client_id = cr.client_id);
```

This assumes that courses are not listed twice for the same user/client.  That is easily taken into account, if that could happen.

The `having` clause checks that the number of matches for the user/client matches the total number of required courses for the client.

Comment: It works but I dont understand why exactly. The part that is confusing me is the last part of the subquery. You reference cr.client_id outside of the subquery. Does this mean the query is going to go through each unique client_id and get it's count?

Comment: I see I need to get a better understanding of correlated subqueries. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I understand now! You're awesome!